# Constructing dates in TSQL

Tags: sql

Trying to construct a date:

```
CAST('9/1/' + YEAR(GETDATE()) AS Datetime) AS test2
```

But it doesnt work?

Would like to get something like '9/1/2010'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't concatenate the string `'9/1'` with the number: `YEAR(GETDATE())`, so try this:

select CAST('9/1/' + CONVERT(varchar(4),YEAR(GETDATE())) AS Datetime) AS test2

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
 CAST( '9/1/' + CAST( YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR ) AS Datetime) AS test2
```

You need to cast the YEAR (integer) to a VARCHAR before you can append it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Select DateAdd(month, 
           dateDiff(month, 0, getdate()) + 9 - MONTH(getdate()),
           0)
```

Comment: This works and it uses fast built-in SQL (Server?) functions instead of string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string formatted YYYYMMDD.